# Android: How to get a custom View's height and width?

Tags: android, view

How do I use `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`? It always returns 0. What is the difference between this and `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`?

Comment: Why can't I use `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` within a View?

Comment: Not a duplicate. Nothing in the question mentions parent dimensions at all!

Comment: Agree with @SMBiggs. It's amuzing that a link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159320/how-to-size-an-android-view-based-on-its-parents-dimensions) was also removed.

Answer (score 75):

Just got a solution to get height and width of a custom view:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    viewWidth = xNew;
    viewHeight = yNew;
}
```

Its working in my case.

Comment: I believe this is the correct method to determine width and height. It's also the simplest.

Comment: one problem is while keyboard comes up this gets called

Comment: If you want to get a size of some view inside whole layout, use this: `someView.measuredWidth` and `someView.measuredHeight`.

Answer (score 12):

Don't try to get them inside its constructor. Try Call them in `onDraw()` method.

Comment: isn't onDraw called continuously? Any action in there might be negative towards the performance.

Comment: Indeed, I think best practice is to listen to the onsizechanged event, and put the width and height in member variables at that time. You can then use them in your ondraw method without having to ask them again.

Comment: don't do anything heavy in onDraw method. onDraw is for drawing only

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following method to get the width and height of the view,
For example,

```
int height = yourView.getLayoutParams().height;
int width = yourView.getLayoutParams().width;
```

This gives the converted value of the view which specified in the XML layout.

Say if the specified value for height is 53dp in XML, you will get the converted value in integer as 80.

Comment: Note that this will give the width / height as long as a width or height is specified. If you set WRAP_CONTENT, this is not going to give a correct width / height. It will return -1, or 0, depending if its "MATCH_PARENT" or "WRAP_CONTENT". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: True, It's give me -1, instead of actual height of scrollview, I need a Scrollview height, in my case I have scrollview and seekbar, need to change it at same time, i.e If I scroll x amount via scrollview at same time seekbar progress should change same as scrollview.

Comment: doesnt work in init  of custom view getLayoutParams comes null

Comment: on inherited view class this method(getLayoutParams) return null.

Answer (score 10):

I was also lost around `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` for a long time.......... later i found `onSizeChanged()` method to be REALLY helpful.

New Blog Post: how to get width and height dimensions of a customView (extends View) in Android http://syedrakibalhasan.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-width-and-height-dimensions.html

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `getHeight()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` is that first method will return actual height of the `View`, the second one will return summary height of `View`'s children. In ohter words, `getHeight()` returns view height, `getMeasuredHeight()` returns height which this view needs to show all it's elements

Comment: It can be same at any case ? I got both value same, is it possible ?

Comment: Sure, it can be the same. For example, if you child has the same height as its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Well `getHeight` gets the height, and `getWidth` gets the width. But you're calling those methods too soon.

If you're calling them in `onCreate` or `onResume`, the view isn't drawn yet. You have to call them after the view has been drawn.

Comment: I was asking the difference between getMeasuredHeight() and getHeight(). Ok how do I get the screen width and height then?