# how to set android:layout_centerInParent="true" attribute in custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

i am continuously searching and trying to sort out a issue in custom view and Relative layout.
i found multiple solution but only few of solution are usefull,but they not fulfilling my requirement completely.

partial solution 1.

[partial solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074937/android-how-to-get-a-custom-views-height-and-width).

via these solution i can manage the height and width of my custom view, but i just want to align my custom view in center of parent RelativeLayout,
code which i am trying throw hit-and-run is below. ;)
 **JAVA CODE**

```
public class MyActiveView extends View {
public Movie mMovie;
public long movieStart;
private int gifId;



public MyActiveView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView();
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight);
}


private void initializeView() {
    InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pj_logo1);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = now;
    }
    if (mMovie != null) {
        int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight() - mMovie.height());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}

public int getActiveResource() {
    return this.gifId;
}

public void setActiveResource(int resId) {
    this.gifId = resId;
    initializeView();
}
}
```

**XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backsourceImagesplash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_blur" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@color/colorTransparentWhite" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="centre">

    <pj.com.pjlib.activity_base.support_class.MyActiveView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i want to set my custom active view layout in centre of its parent Relative Layout, but stuked in it. any help will be appreciated.

[image: i want result like this.]
[image: but result of my code is]

check the alignment of both image,i am trying for attribute android:layout_centerInParent="true", according to Relative layout support the "congrats image" should be in center, but it's not happening.

so i am thinking,i missed something in my custom view class but what is that, i don't know.

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more details, and maybe provide a screenshot of the actual result.

Comment: Can you show what is the actual result? Or at least describe it . Edit the original question, so that other people can better understand the issue.

Comment: images and extra support line added please check @Roberto

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma did you get any solution??? if yes please help me also

Comment: @curiousMind i used Dialog fragment  with transparent window background, this is not the solution but it helps me to achieve the same. please vote up the question to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change android:gravity="centre" with android:gravity="center" in Relative Layout. I think this will helpful to you.