# Margin set programmatically not applied instantly to the view

Tags: android, layoutparams

I'm creating a ImageView programmatically :

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
   lp.setMargins(4,4,4,4);

   ImageView color = new ImageView(this);
   color.setLayoutParams(lp);
   colorPicker.addView(color); //adding view to linearlayout
   Log.i("X", "" + color.getX());
   ...
```

im trying to retrieve `color's` x poistion via `color.getX()` , but for some reason it returns `0` instead of `4` meaning its not taking the margin into account

also after doing some search in the docs i found `requestLayout()` might solve this, but it doesnt help either

> public void setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom) 
>  
>   Sets the margins, in pixels. A call to requestLayout() needs to be done so that the new margins are taken into account. Left and right margins may be overriden by requestLayout() depending on layout direction.

**UPDATE**

if i call `color.getX()` inside onClick listener it returns 4 as expected

Comment: `getX()` returns co-ordinates according to View's parent. Add the View to some parent `ViewGroup` first.

Comment: the view is added into LinearLayout , just didnt added it to the code above

Comment: Shouldn't be the log statement be placed _after_ you add view to layout ?

Comment: indeed.. still return's 0 though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width`, `height`, `margins`, etc. of a `View` aren't applied inmediately, you need to wait for the `UI` to be sized and laid out on the screen.

[getWidth() returns 0 if set by android:layout_width="match_parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592930/getwidth-returns-0-if-set-by-androidlayout-width-match-parent)

Try this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = color.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        Log.i("X", "" + color.getX());

    } 
});
```

You will need to make "color" variable `final` or `global` to be able to access it inside the `listener`.

Comment: thanks! that does the trick indeed :) , just this.layout should be color i guess