# Drawing Latitude and Longitude to screen

Tags: java, android

If i calculate the X and Y axis from latitude and longitude like so:

```
private static final int    EARTH_RADIUS    = 6371;
private static final double FOCAL_LENGTH    = 500;

                    latitude = latitude * Math.PI / 180;
                    longitude = longitude * Math.PI / 180;

                    double x = EARTH_RADIUS * Math.sin(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude);
                    double y = EARTH_RADIUS * Math.sin(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude);
                    double z = EARTH_RADIUS * Math.cos(latitude);

                    double projectedX = x * FOCAL_LENGTH / (FOCAL_LENGTH + z);
                    double projectedY = y * FOCAL_LENGTH / (FOCAL_LENGTH + z);
```

How would i ensure that the X and Y points are drawn within the screen? Ie., have the screen represent a 2d view of the world such that you will never be able to draw a point off of the screen?

Latitude and Longitude are values ranging from -90 to 90 and -180 to 180..

**I do not want to use google services - no MapView or anything related to google maps...**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your device width and height and divide it with latitude and longitude ranges.

For instances, device width is 300px and longitude ranges from -180 to 180. It means 300 divide with 360.

Comment: Maybe you are getting 0 value of your device height. Check the answer out on how get width. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14593023/1799322

Comment: hmm no, i'm getting 724