# getmeasuredheight() and getmeasuredwidth() returns 0 after View.measure()

Tags: android, layout, view

After measuring a `View` with a **constant dimensions** with `view.measure()`, the `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasureWidth()` is returning 0.

**layout_view.xml**, layout which is inflated to create the view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
</FrameLayout>
```

function which measures the dimensions

```
public void measureView(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view,null,false);

    view.measure( View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    Log.d(TAG,"Error width : " + view.getMeasuredWidth());
    Log.d(TAG,"Error height : " + view.getMeasuredHeight());

}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592930/getwidth-returns-0-if-set-by-androidlayout-width-match-parent

Comment: @GiruBhai i tried using ViewTreeObserver, its also not working

Comment: `View.MeasureSpec.*` can't be used directly, check my answer below.

Answer (score 17):

When you call `view.getMeasuredWidth()` in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`, the `view` has not been drawn yet. So you need to add a listener and will get a callback when the `view` is being drawn. Just like this in my code:

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
if (vto.isAlive()) {
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int viewWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            // handle viewWidth here...

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** Remove the listener for better performance!

Don't call `vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)` to remove the listener. Call it like this:

```
vto.getViewTreeObserver()
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to work in all tested cases but now I see the getMeasuredWidth() returning 0 in production for some users :(

Comment: Thank you! I was using ```OnPreDrawListener``` before (but seems it is not compatible with some devices 4.4.4 and 6.0.1). Using ```onGlobalLayout``` and removing the listener just when ```height > 0``` it works perfectly.

Comment: What is `v`? It came out of nowhere.

Comment: For some reason `getMeasuredWidth`only returns the "right" value after scrolling take place. Is there another way to trigger a correct measurement?

Answer (score 7):

Are you measuring the view in `onCreate()`. The view isn't drawn yet. You have to wait until a time after the view is drawn before you can measure it.

Simple solution for this is to post a runnable to the layout. The runnable will be executed after the layout has happened.

For more info [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425466/991085)

**Edit**
try to change

```
view.measure( View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

to

```
view.measure( View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```

Comment: i am measuring the the view in in onclick method. To avoid the issue you pointed out i am explicitly measuring the view with `view.measure()`

Comment: i tried this may also, but still the result is zero

Answer (score 4):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
     int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
     int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if your measured view has visibility set to gone, measuring will return 0. You can set it to visible, measure, and then set back to gone, all from code.

Comment: it is set to visible by default

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `View.MeasureSpec.*` directly in `measure` call. Instead first `makeMeasureSpec()` and then use it to invoke `measure()`:

```
final int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT/*can be match_parent or some exact value*/, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
final int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT/*can be match_parent or some exact value*/, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

Comment: Thanks, but currently Kotling restricts passing this value (WRAP_CONTENT = -2 < 0). In my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739033/2914140 helped in `onCreateView()`, simply called view.measure(0, 0). In other events you should use `getViewTreeObserver()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592930/getwidth-returns-0-if-set-by-androidlayout-width-match-parent.

Comment: ```View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);```not work, it says ```Value must be ≥ 0 (was -2)```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone was experiencing this problem with ImageView:

I noticed that if your ImageView doesn't have "android:src" set (i.e. you change it dynamically) it will always return zero from getMeasuredWidth/Height.

A simple workaround would be to set a placeholder for view.

Comment: getHeight/getMeasuredHeight still gives 0, after setting placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getViewTreeObserver` in `onCreate/onCreateView` and other events.

```
fun setGlobalLayoutListener(view: View, method: () -> Unit) {
    val vto1 = view.viewTreeObserver
    if (vto1.isAlive) {
        vto1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                val vto2 = view.viewTreeObserver
                if (vto2.isAlive) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        vto2.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    } else {
                        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                        vto2.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                    }
                    // Your actions are here:
                    method()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And call it: `setGlobalLayoutListener(view) {updateUI(view)}`.

I also tried

```
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
```

and then called `view.control.measuredWidth` in `onCreateView()/onViewCreated()`. But in some emulators (API 19) it returned wrong results.