# Android getWidth() return 0 in View's onDraw

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
    if (myView == null) {
        myView = new View(mContext) {
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                final float width = (float)getWidth();
                ......
            }
        };

        addView(myView);
    }

    requestLayout();
```

The width in my code is always 0 although the size of the mContext is not zero. Can anybody advise what could be the possible reason I got 0 for width? Thanks

Comment: Please show the Layout XML

Comment: Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159320/how-to-size-an-android-view-based-on-its-parents-dimensions

Comment: I think the issue is my parent view is not shown then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to record the dimensions of the canvas in the `onSizeChanged` handler and then use them in the `onDraw` handler.

```
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasWidth = w;
    canvasHeight = h;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    final float width = (float)canvasWidth;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try.

Comment: I accept your answer is not because it solved my issue. It's because I appreciate your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Being a rookie I think your new view is blank thats y its width and height is coming 0. 
May b u should try to set its layoutparameter giving some hardcode height and width.

Currently onmeasure has nothing to measure.
May B . :P